# How to get value from key (REQUEST RESPONSE)

Tags: python, json, request

I want to get the value of "fingerprint".

This is what the request response looks like:

```
{"fingerprint": "1026855718843854889.uBLov7n2_k-Z_4LiAFnTDOerMXc", "assignments": [[3816091942, 3, 0, -1, 0], [4130837190, 0, 10, -1, 0], [852550504, 3, 1, -1, 0], [2599708267, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1365487849, 6, 1, -1, 0], [3128009767, 0, 10, -1, 0], [2973729510, 2, 1, -1, 0], [1260103069, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2003494159, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2458926251, 1, 6, -1, 2], [4027800, 1, 6, -1, 3], [51193042, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2063302207, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2634540382, 3, 1, -1, 0], [427713714, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3316720711, 0, 1, -1, 1], [1126477623, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2617218444, 4, 1, -1, 2], [3615263239, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3035674767, 0, 1, -1, 0], [261678880, 0, 1, -1, 0], [144783748, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2311413706, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1304635016, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1609782151, 0, 1, -1, 2], [1047093347, 0, 1, -1, 2], [3354177721, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3643362751, 0, 1, -1, 0], [698017395, 0, 1, -1, 0], [902020832, 3, 3, -1, 1], [3346844407, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3753034466, 1, 2, -1, 0], [3125584553, 1, 1, -1, 0], [219203323, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2854861606, 0, 1, -1, 1], [2416791266, 1, 1, -1, 0], [3884403666, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2780619238, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2839301427, 1, 1, -1, 0], [1567199723, 0, 1, -1, 1], [2237617796, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2481496956, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1305004983, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3121542871, 1, 1, -1, 0], [1175582167, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2012365622, 0, 2, -1, 0], [3615787841, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2544296633, 5, 0, -1, 0], [4257117014, 1, 2, -1, 0], [754424255, 0, 0, -1, 0], [282861292, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2950595281, 2, 1, -1, 0], [2496945544, 0, 0, -1, 0], [3662016164, 3, 2, -1, 0], [2486607747, 0, 0, -1, 0], [2736193736, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1138665623, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3542498455, 0, 1, -1, 0], [723256323, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3866818837, 0, 0, -1, 0], [3450899088, 1, 1, -1, 0], [3656796460, 3, 3, -1, 3], [334012295, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1685515200, 0, 18, -1, 0], [1748842958, 1, 1, -1, 0], [899439768, 1, 1, -1, 0], [4100056516, 0, 1, -1, 3], [3047034364, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1639141880, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2140622532, 2, 1, -1, 5], [852840006, 0, 1, -1, 1], [799757083, 0, 3, -1, 0], [1308053712, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1814483290, 0, 1, -1, 0], [4221006726, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2866205130, 6, 2, -1, 1], [3074844387, 0, 2, -1, 0], [2855612301, 0, 1, -1, 0], [4084522269, 0, 1, -1, 0], [3061393440, 1, 1, -1, 0], [4156073260, 3, 2, -1, 0], [1613012371, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1398673921, 1, 1, -1, 0], [1312831343, 0, 2, -1, 0], [3557480712, 0, 1, -1, 0], [4239204703, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2682412013, 0, 1, -1, 0], [853403133, 4, 1, -1, 0], [2491005019, 4, 1, -1, 0], [3889077804, 2, 1, -1, 0], [4079214319, 2, 1, -1, 0], [2447247632, 6, 2, -1, 1], [2224597644, 0, 1, -1, 0], [381231361, 0, 1, -1, 3], [4285126928, 1, 1, -1, 5], [731344995, 1, 1, -1, 2], [275647339, 0, 2, -1, 1], [2147107212, 0, 2, -1, 1], [971239104, 2, 1, -1, 0], [1687110464, 1, 1, -1, 0], [2556391943, 2, 1, -1, 0], [976159363, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2036642634, 0, 1, -1, 0], [4028412949, 1, 2, -1, 0], [1034661306, 0, 1, -1, 0], [980555040, 0, 2, -1, 3], [3124003316, 1, 1, -1, 0], [488500683, 1, 1, -1, 0], [3182051840, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2514746297, 0, 1, -1, 0], [2988525176, 1, 1, -1, 0], [3576084512, 0, 1, -1, 0], [1499121765, 0, 1, -1, 0]]}
```

I want to only get the value of fingerprint which is: "1026855718843854889.uBLov7n2_k-Z_4LiAFnTDOerMXc".

My code:

```
fingerprintr = requests.get(fingerprintURL, headers=fingerprintheaders).json
```

I get "TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable" if I try to do the following:

```
fingerprint = fingerprintr["fingerprint"]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You forgot the `()` after `.json`, i.e. to call the `Response.json()` method

Comment: `.json` is a method, not a property: you need to call it. Therefore `fingerprint = requests.get(...).json()["fingerprint"]` will give you the value, if `"fingerprint"` key exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `json()` function:

```
fingerprintr = requests.get(fingerprintURL, headers=fingerprintheaders).json()
```